# Display/Hide button when writing on autocomplete input

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a form to manage personal informations with name and address.
After page loading, the form display name information and address information in input text.

1/ If I change the address, an autocomplete js display list of google maps address. At the moment I would like to hide submit button until click on address.

2/ If there is no click or right adress result I would like to erase the input, display the "placeholder" and display button submit.

Here my jquery script:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){           
         $('#adress').keyup(function() {
            $('#validate_info').hide();
         });
    });
</script>
```

Here Html/php code:

```
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="George Lake"></input>
<input type="text" id="address" placeholder="17 Street Lane, Leeds, Royaume-Uni" ></input>
<button type="submit" id="validate_info">Validate</button>
```

Footer script page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places&language=en-AU"></script>
<script>
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($("#address")[0], {});

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        console.log(place.address_components);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will help you.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
     $(document).ready(function(){           
        $('#adress').keyup(function() {
           $('#validate_info').css("display", "none");
        });
     });
</script>
```

Your footer script page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places&language=en-AU"></script>
<script>
       var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($("#address")[0], {});

       google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
           var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
           // Check here that place is empty or not
           if(place == ''){
               $('#address').value("");
               $('#validate_info').css("display", "block");
           }
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. But I would like to display button submit if the input are erased and the placeholder display the first result (from page loading)

Comment: I have edited my answer. I have changed button css button attribute from 'none' to 'block'. So now it will display submit button.

Comment: sorry but If I erase all in the #address the #validate_info doesn't appear :-/

Comment: It might happen for different reason. Put alert in if condition and check that it come in to the condition or not. Because for display button I have gave you a proper code.